# Rails 4 ActionMailer Throwing Undefined Local Variable/Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am fairly new to Rails and this is my first time creating a mailer. I have a user model which contains name, role, and email (all strings). I am having a problem with my app, which is throwing an error; it says that user is undefined, even though I thought I had passed it in via my controller.

I've looked through several posts, the Rails Guides, API Dock, and I still can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "receipts@example.com"
  def receipt_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Thank you!')
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user, param_method: :user_params

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        UserMailer.receipt_email(@user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:role, :email)
    end
end
```

**Error Message:**

undefined local variable or method `user' for UserMailer:Class

```
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:3:in `<class:UserMailer>'
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `block in update'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `update'
```

Comment: What's the view for that mailer look like? Any chance you're referencing `user` there instead of `@user` ?

Comment: It's all just plain text - I was trying to make it as simple as possible. There's no variables.

Comment: That's a bit unusual. The error message should mention what file and line is generating the error.  What does that say?

Comment: Trace: app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:3:in `<class:UserMailer>'
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `show'

Comment: And: NameError in UsersController#update

Comment: Can you imclude the whole users_controller.rb in particular the show method

Comment: Sorry - that was supposed to be 'update'... Copied from wrong error page.

Comment: Ok, when you get around to showing the correct error trace, post a comment.

Comment: app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:3:in `<class:UserMailer>'
    app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `block in update'
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `update'

Comment: Added error trace to question

Answer (score 0):

So I did some more testing and retyped the entire thing from scratch - turns out that my indenting wasn't done with just 2 spaces, like the rest of my files.

**Note to self - always check indentation first!!!**